# Combine modules while treating them independently with Require.js

Tags: requirejs, js-amd

With require.js and the r.js optimizer, how can I combine two modules, for
example Backbone and Underscore, into a single package/module, and then be able
to load the package and get a reference to the dependecy with a call to either of
the modules which were combined. Is this possible?

For example, assuming I have managed to get Underscore and Backbone
into a single module, then I would be able to load
the entire package (which would include underscore) with the following code,
and backbone would be injected to the function.

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone){
  // My code...
})
```